# python generate all combination from word list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create simple script to generate all posibile username started from name of user.

example input:

```
craciun florin ionel
```

output needed :

```
craciun.florin
craciun.florin.ionel
craciun.ionel
florin.ionel
florin.craciun
ionel.florin.craciun
craciunflorin
ionel.craciun.florin
....
```

I tryied to use the `itertools` tool, but output is not ok for my needed.

My current code :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> names = ['craciun','florin','ionel']
>>> keywords = ['.'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(names, repeat=2) if i[0] != i[1]] 
>>> keywords
['craciun.florin', 'craciun.ionel', 'florin.craciun', 'florin.ionel', 'ionel.craciun', 'ionel.florin']
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to use `itertools.permutations()` twice, one with `r=2`, another one with `r=3`, though this might not be very efficient and "Pythonic". 
For example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> my_list
['alfa', 'beta', 'gamma']
>>> result = []
>>> 
>>> # Round 1 with r=2 
>>> for combo in itertools.permutations(my_list, 2):
...     result.append(combo)
...
>>> result
[('alfa', 'beta'), ('alfa', 'gamma'), ('beta', 'alfa'), ('beta', 'gamma'), ('gamma', 
'alfa'), ('gamma', 'beta')]
>>>
>>> # Round 2 with r=3
>>> for combo in itertools.permutations(my_list, 3):
...     result.append(combo)
...
>>> result
[('alfa', 'beta'), ('alfa', 'gamma'), ('beta', 'alfa'), ('beta', 'gamma'), ('gamma', 
'alfa'), ('gamma', 'beta'), ('alfa', 'beta', 'gamma'), ('alfa', 'gamma', 'beta'), 
('beta', 'alfa', 'gamma'), ('beta', 'gamma', 'alfa'), ('gamma', 'alfa', 'beta'), 
('gamma', 'beta', 'alfa')]
```

And you could loop through this result list to do the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

One liner, because we love them:

```
keywords = [ ".".join(i) for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(names, r) for r in [2, 3])]
```

Result:

```
['craciun.florin', 'craciun.ionel', 'florin.craciun', 'florin.ionel', 'ionel.craciun', 'ionel.florin', 'craciun.florin.ionel', 'craciun.ionel.florin', 'florin.craciun.ionel', 'florin.ionel.craciun', 'ionel.craciun.florin', 'ionel.florin.craciun']
```